# How to link(relate) this two tables MySQL

Tags: mysql

**Problem**

1. A student registers for a course.
2. Add that courses name, and registration date, to the `student_courses` that can be identified with      the student that was registered
3. Combine the two tables to show the `courses` the student is registered to.

How should I do this, what is the relationship the `Student` and `student_courses` have in order to achieve my goal.

[image]

Comment: Did you design this schema?  Can you change it?  It's pretty awful.

Comment: @SeanBright Not really, the data was given to me, I just made it in workbench, but I could change it if I knew any better :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added a many to many relationship between Courses, and Student, and a new table was generated. In that table then I added a date filed.

Answer (score 2):

What I would do is add a field to student_courses being the student's personalNumber and also adding the courseId to student_courses. This way it is easy to join all 3 tables

Comment: So what is the relationship between `courses` and `student_courses` I mean one-to-one Identified, or Non-Identified ?

Comment: Well, what I was thinking is the 'courses' was a general list of courses available and the 'student_courses' would be the courses that the student is in, therefore needing the student id number in the table and a link to the course table using the courseId

Comment: Yea that I was thinking to, but should it be a one-to-one relationship between `student` and `student_courses` ? Or it does not really matter that much ?

Comment: It probably won't be one-to-one as you will probably have 1 student with multiple classes, so you shouldn't need to have the student in there multiple times, in-fact it would be wise not to have them in there multiple times

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right track with the **student_courses** table.

Because the relationship between the student and course can be many-to-many (i.e. multiple students can register for multiple courses) there is a need for a relational table to link a  course to the student.

student_courses should store a foreign key reference to the primary key on student and course and include any registration-related fields (like registration date). By doing this you can generate a sql statement that builds a list of all courses the student is related to:

```
select
    sc.registrationdate, c.*
from
    student_courses sc
    join student s on s.personalNumber = sc.student_id
    join courses c on c.courseId = sc.courses_id
where 
    s.personalNumber = 123;
```

or if you want to find all the students related to a course:

```
select
    s.personalNumber, s.firstName, s.lastName
from
    student_courses sc
    join student s on s.personalNumber = sc.student_id
    join courses c on c.courseId = sc.courses_id
where 
    c.courseId = 123;
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: This helps, but to clarify, what you suggest the relationship of `student` and `student_courses` be, one-to-one or something else. And how about `student_courses` with `courses`. Cheers

Comment: The relationship we are building is between courses and students. i.e. there are no students without courses and no courses without students. student_courses always requires a student and a course to be entered and will be many-to-many (that is, student 1 will have register with multiple courses and course a will have multiple students)